# My C program for a basic clock is not fully running. Are there any adjustments I need to make?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Below is my code and output. I have tried to debug it several times but still can't get it to fully run. Any ideas on how I might make my code fully run?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int h, m, s;
    int d = 1000;
    int numberRead = 0;

    printf("Set time:\n");
    do {
        printf("Hours:");
        numberRead = scanf("%d", &h);
        while (numberRead != 1) {
            printf("Please insert a positive integer.\n");
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
            printf("Hours:");
            numberRead = scanf("%d", &h);
        }
        if (h > 23 || h < 0) {
            printf("ERROR! Please insert integers ranging from 0 to 24.\n");
        }
    } while (h > 23 || h < 0);

    do {
        printf("Minutes:");
        numberRead = scanf("%d", &m);
        while (numberRead != 1) {
            printf("Please insert a positive integer.\n");
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
            printf("Minutes:");
            numberRead = scanf("%d", &m);
        }
        if (h > 60 || h < 0) {
            printf("ERROR! Please insert integers ranging from 0 to 60.\n");
        }
    } while (h > 60 || h < 0);

    do {
        printf("Seconds:");
        numberRead = scanf("%d", &s);
        while (numberRead != 1) {
            printf("Please insert a positive integer.\n");
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
            printf("Seconds:");
            numberRead = scanf("%d", &s);
        }
        if (h > 60 || h < 0) {
            printf("ERROR! Please insert integers ranging from 0 to 60.\n");
        }
    } while (h > 60 || h < 0);

    while (1) {
        s++;
        if (s > 59) {
            m++;
            s = 0;
        }
        if (m > 59) {
            h++;
            m = 0;
        }
        if (h > 23) {
            h = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\nClock:");
    printf("\n%02d: %02d: %02d", h, m, s);
    sleep(d); /* The function sleep slows down the while loop and makes it more like a real clock.*/
    system("cls");/*This clears the screen; Try to know more about the two functions.*/
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

[image: This is an image of the output]

I am not able to receive the output for the clock.

I have debugged the code several times but nothing is changing; I keep on receiving the same output over and over.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also please try to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). And please don't use single-letter variable names, give variables relevant names, like `hour` instead of `h`.

Comment: Your program doesn't print any output for the clock, so why do you expect output for the clock? Well, it does, but only after the loop runs forever. What is after forever?

Comment: What did you find out when you were debugging, at which step exactly does the program start doing something different than you expect?

Comment: `while(h>60||h<0);` doesn't look like a very relevant check, at least not for this particular planet.

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]");` where is the variable

Comment: `while (1) {` how do you get out of this loop? you scanf for `m` and `s` but you test `h`

Comment: @rioV8: `scanf("%*[^\n]")` does not store anything into a variable, the `*` suppresses assignment. It attempts to read and discard all bytes until it reaches a newline or the end of file. The newline, if found, is left pending in the input stream. To properly discard the rest of the input line, there should be another call : `scanf("%*1[\n]");` or possibly `scanf("%*c");` or just `getchar()`.  I prefer writing a function with a `getchar()` loop so I can test for end of file.

Comment: @chqrlie I know C for a long time but have never seen this usage, and I see it in a newbie code snippet ;-)

Comment: @rioV8: my credo: learn something new everyday...

Comment: @user253751 'What is after forever?' - Dutch band ft. Floor Jansen vocals.  Superb symphonic metal, (pre-Nightwish:)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you test `h` in all 3 `do`-`while` entry loops. `do`-`while` loops are confusing and error prone because the end test is not written in the right place for most programmers' line of thought.  In your case this leads to duplicate tests and for some reason, you only updated the bounds in these tests after copying the first loop for the minutes and seconds entry.
- you have an infinite loop increasing the time for ever, without updating the display... Hence nothing appears to happen but your CPU is happily draining your the power supply.  The `printf` calls and the `sleep()` system call should be moved inside this loop.

Here is a modified version using an ancillary function to avoid redundant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* read and discard the current input line. return EOF at end of file */
int flush_stdin(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

/* read an integer in a given range */
int get_integer(const char *prompt, int min, int max) {
    int n = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
            /* silently consume the rest of the input line */
            flush_stdin();
            if (n >= min && n <= max)
                break;
            printf("ERROR! Please enter an integer ranging from %d to %d.\n", min, max);
        } else {
            /* invalid input: read and discard the input line */
            if (flush_stdin() == EOF) {
                printf("unexpected end of file\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Please insert a positive integer.\n");
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    int h, m, s, i;

    printf("Set time:\n");
    h = get_integer("Hours:", 0, 23);
    m = get_integer("Minutes:", 0, 59);
    s = get_integer("Seconds:", 0, 59);

    /* run for 2 minutes */
    for (i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
        printf("Clock: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", h, m, s);
        sleep(1);  /* wait for 1 second */
        /* if running on Windows, you might want to use Sleep(1000) instead */
        s++;
        if (s > 59) {
            m++;
            s = 0;
        }
        if (m > 59) {
            h++;
            m = 0;
        }
        if (h > 23) {
            h = 0;
        }
    }
    /* clear the screen */
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```